# Retrieving voicemails from android programmatically

Tags: android, voicemail

Is it possible to retrieve voicemails from Android phone programmatically and forward them? Does the Android API allow one to do so?

Comment: Note that the way voicemail is handled can vary between ROMs, manufacturers, and carriers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Most voicemail is accessed by dialing a number, and entering a passcode. You would have to programatically do all that via a phone call.

Comment: Thanks for the info. How does Google Voice retrieve my voicemails and email?

Comment: You should do a little research on how [Google Voice works](http://support.google.com/voice/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=115073). They have their own service which provides voicemail service that is completely independent of your carrier voicemail.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart I want to know if it is possible to read voicemail programatically in android?

Comment: @AnujKumarJha It's a smartphone - anything is possible. Now whether there's some API already written, or whether you'd have to do it yourself is where the question lies.

Comment: That's what my question is i mean is it possible programatically?? cause on many website i found that voicemails are network dependent so not possible programatically.If yes can you mention db name or api which can be used?